# create function of object prototype

Tags: javascript, prototyping, object

I am reading "Javascript : The good Parts" to improve my Javascript bases and knowledge. I was reading stuff about `prototype` and I encountered in this function :

```
var stooge = { ... } 
if(typeof Object.create !== 'function'){
   Object.create = function(o) {
   var F = function () {};
   F.prototype = o;
   return new F();
   };
}
var another_stooge = Object.create(stooge);
```

I didn't really get the meaning and the benefit of creating this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only a shim for the standard [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) function which isn't available in some browsers (yes, you guessed which one).

Note that it's not complete : it doesn't do everything that is done by `Object.create` but it's probably enough for the author.

As for why the author wanted to use `Object.create` instead of a explicit prototype based OOP, it's probably because it's a little simpler.